# Creating a convincing mafia?

Tags: society, humans, economy, politics, secret-society

I am currently in the process of creating my own world for an upcoming RPG, in a Victorian Era/Industrial Revolution/Steam Age setting. It's not overly steampunk but light elements of it are acceptable, as well as some dark fantasy/horror here and there (inspiration from H.P. Lovecraft's works, without going full Cthulhu).

Anyways. I've always loved the idea of mafias and how they function, operate and exist fascinates me.

My question is the following :

**What are some good resources out there that explain how a mafia sets its roots, how it becomes an important and recognised entity and how they maintain that power?**

Some extra questions that may help understand what I am looking for :

- What are the essential elements to take into account when creating a believable mafia that has an impact in a city or region?
- Could they control for example all grain sources, aka food? How would they go about that and how would they exploit it?
- Could there be multiple families squabbling at the top over who controls what?
- How does a mafia get rooted into a city so deeply that even the authorities don't dare approach them?
- What makes a mafia powerful?
- How does a mafia begin?
- How can I make the mafia impactful and interesting enough that my players will recognise them without just kicking down the door and plowing through to the "big boss"?
- What am I missing?

Any and all ideas are welcome, I'd love to read/watch more on the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: How the mafia grows is a well established subject. What have you searched and found on the topic?

Comment: Welcome to the site Frazic. In this stack we prefer to answer single questions that can have an objectively correct answer. More to the point, the objective here is to start by TRYING to build the world, and then presenting specific problems that you've encountered. You skipped that step here. You should start by reading up on organized crime, TRY to create a convincing mafia, and then bring any problems you encounter at that point here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organized_crime

Comment: Your questions sounds like blurb on the back cover of "big book of Sycylian Mafia" with a star "all answers inside".

Comment: I'm flagging this as needing focus - your question is too broad right now.  Answering your question could easily be an entire book (or volumes of books).

Comment: Carl Sifakis, [*The Mafia Encyclopedia*](https://archive.org/details/CarlSifakisTheMafiaEncyclopedia), 2005. Cesare Mori, [*The Last Struggle with the Mafia*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.72638), English translatio by Orlo Williams, 1933; this is a first person narrative of the Fascist "[iron prefect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesare_Mori)" who brought the Sicilian Mafia to its knees in the 1920s. (Links go to Archive.org.)

Comment: Voted to reopen because OP isn't asking to answer the questions, but for references that might help him answer the questions on his own.

Comment: Hi, I see how this question was misunderstood. I'm asking specifically for resources I could look into, documents, websites, books, videos, anything. I'm not asking for all these questions to be answered here, I'm asking for research material, but maybe that was not clear enough? If that is something that is not permitted then I understand, but I think the votes to close may have been done for the wrong reasons?

Thanks for understanding

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle, OP is not telling what they have already found.

Comment: My tuppence worth: Watch [Peaky Blinders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2442560/) if you get a chance ([Wiki-Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaky_Blinders)) - a cracking good story, several seasons are out on DVD or streaming services. Gives a view of the rise and rise of a Birmingham (UK) street gang - all the way to the top - even into the British parliament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cities have a high level of immigration, it may be an outgrowth of this.  In the U.S. mafias arose from within immigrant communities in cities.   Immigrants to the U.S> would typically settle in neighborhoods with immigrants from their home lands and create ethnic neighborhoods.   China Towns, Little Italies, Germantowns, Little Havannas, ect. exist in just about every city (though sometimes not as so named).  Back during the time period you were looking at, the established members of this community would often look out for new members and some were a bit less honest about it than others.

Typically, organized crime starts out as protection raquets... some thuggish looking fellows enter your store or place of work or even knock on your home door, welcome you to the community, comment on some precious possession you have and the real shame of losing it would be, then offer to protect you and yours for a fee.  If you pay them regularly, then nothing happens to you... if you don't pay... well, it's like those nice thuggish looking men told you... some thugs came about one day and busted up your family or your property... lucky for you, the nice thuggish men will come back to express sympathy for your loss and again offer there services.    What are the odds?

Now, from here, you can get into other enterprises by say instead of offering a payment, how about offer to pay for the rebuild of the bakery... these nice thuggish men will protected you, and invest in your buisness, and all you have to do is hire a few thugs and not ask questions about what they do with the buisness with their part of the controlling interest.  Sure, Paulie, Joey, and Vinny were here with a guy you never saw before, late at night, and showed him the butcher's equipment... and then you never saw the same guy again... that's legit, right?

And yes, you can have multiple organized crime groups in a single city.  NYC has Five Families... and that's just the Italian mobs...  They also have Irish mobs, Russian Mobs, Hispanic cartels, African-American Gangs, and Chinese Tongs and Triads (surprisingly the Japanese Yakuza isn't that active in NYC... but they are pretty powerful in Japan and western U.S. states).

Typically the Mafia's power and difficulty in rooting out stems for the "Strangers on a Train" scenario.   Say the big boss wants Tony dead.  He's not gonna kill Tony, the police know he's a big mob player... but he can casually say to one of his flunkies that he would like Tony to be made an example of... Suddenly the police are fishing out Tony from the river and all evidence points to the flunky who was too eager to please the Boss, who was out of town when Tony disappeared and only returned after the body was found.  Of course, the Boss will candidly tell police that he's glad Tony is gone, but it's unfortunate that it was done by such unpleasent means... he never seriously wanted Tony to die.

Now, take that situation, and realize the orders to kill Tony may have come from higher powers... and when to people so far down the totem pole, the boss would have never known them (In The U.S. RICO laws got around this problem to some degree, but they weren't a thing until at least the 1970s).

Almost all organized crime rituals will have some form of initiation right, usually involving the cultural lore they are related too.   Though not always, there may be dress codes of sorts that all the members wear certain clothing items or colors (all wear Fedoras or all wear green scarves), though some can have body modification (typical of Far East Asian gangs, tatoos or stubbed fingers (Yakuza, often a punishment).).  Russian tattooed criminals typically signify jail sentence and not mafia affiliation.  Western European and Latin organizations tend to have rituals tied to Catholic symbols as they were often Catholic to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much for this highly detailed answer, it helps a lot and is giving me tons of ideas ! 
What did you mean when you said : 
`Now, take that situation, and realize the orders to kill Tony may have come from higher powers... and when to people so far down the totem pole, the boss would have never known them`

Comment: So in most Mafias, one of the benfits of giving some of your cut to your boss was that you were protected from other members in your organization (all of whom are criminals of some color).   And his protection was backed by his own boss, and so on until you got to the very top (The Don).  Typically you couldn't kill certain people without the Don's say so (in addition to your own organiation members, the protection might go to rival gangs under some color of truce and police, because cops tend to react just like mafias to the death of a member).